# Caching computed results for each user - would having a table dedicated to each user make sense?

Tags: python, mysql, database-design

We are sketching out how a system would work. The problem is that have a set of items with a computed value for each item.  Say for example you like players in the nba and there are a certain set of players that you have shown preferences about.

Examples might be:

1. number of games played
2. rebounding
3. scoring
4. assists
5. minutes played per game
6. players that your other friends like
7. likelihood of being traded - you often want players that are going to be traded

There's approx 500 players in the nba.  From a performance pov, querying is cost prohibitive - throwing in other people' s preferences etc.... We have been thinking of doing an alternative approaches. One approach is a NoSQL where each user gets written a document of each player. To be honest, this seems like too many unkowns as I have zero experience. Another approach is where each person in the system would get a table dedicated to them. Perhaps write out the table definition via cron on a nightly basis and when the user logs in, do a create table statement and then have a dedicated query against that. This sounds really ugly to me too (although feasible). We could also certainly have a single table where each user has a row for each player. I'd rather not premise the whole system off self-joins though. It seems to take querying off-line and we could feasibly measure 1000 players against these different parameters.

Are there other ideas that I'm missing? I don't want anything too esoteric - preferably just MySQL and Python. Would be using InnoDB and not so concerned about splitting up the tables per database per host issue.

Any other ideas or realword experience would be appreciated? I'm sure this has been solved many times before.

thx

Comment: This is a little too vague. If you avoid joins and index properly you can get high performance out of even a large MySQL database. If your service is a hit and you need tons of performance later you can cluster the MySQL, so it isn't a dead end. There are a lot of strategies to speed up queries.

Comment: I agree it's vague; clustering to read-onlys makes sense but looking a little bit for alternatives before making that step. A previous DBA totally dropped the ball on a cluster install and I've been hesitant to use it since.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using mongodb right now for the first time and I find it to be really awesome in the way it lets you represent a document pretty much like an object oriented class structure. You can easily have a document per user that stores any number of embedded documents. Your players can be in a nested dictionary or a list, and you can index on player names. Then when you request a user, there are NO joins. You have all your data. Plus there is a flexible schema so you can always just add more fields whenever you want.

As for mysql table-per-user, I agree its really messy and can get out of control.

Another alternative is you could look into a key-value store like Redis for caching purposes since its in memory, it would be fast as well.

Comment: right, this makes sense; I guess my question is that I know a couple of groups that have gone mongo but then have switched back. the mysql-table-per-user does feel really inelegant. Maybe I'll prototype it up and see how I feel about it. I like it because it would give me the power and familiarity of sql with the ability to isolate to a high degree. The other reason I ask is that there seems to be a lot of work in MySQL that I'm not that familiar with (memory databases or http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2011/12/22/optimizing-innodb-for-creating-30000-tables-and-nothing-else/ ).

Comment: continued: I've heard good things about redis. I've heard mixed about mongo

Comment: I have been searching quite a lot on mongo before deciding to use it and I actually hadn't heard much mixed responses. What I have heard is a lot of questions regarding approaching mongo from a mysql mindset and how to organize. But generally people with experience end up providing great answers. My main take on mongo is that it scales exceptionally well and easily. I have been meaning to use Redis but at this point have only tried it out casually.